# How to force Emacs display of `*Messages*` window

Tags: emacs

I'm printing a message like this

```
(interactive "P")
(message "test")
```

If the *Messages* buffer is not visible in the frame, it should appear as a split window. I've seen some softwares do this (maybe tramp) not sure how to do this.

I already read http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Messages.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this works

```
(defun my-kbd-x-hook (&optional use-generic-p)
  "Curl call"
  (interactive "P")
  (message "hi")
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Messages"))
```

Comment: **`view-echo-area-messages`** is more like it. It's what you get when you click `mouse-1` in the echo area.

Comment: The benefit of the function recommended above by @Drew is that the `*Messages*` buffer will be created in the proper mode using the function `(messages-buffer)` if it does not exist yet or return the correct buffer if it already exists.  To see the subtle difference between the function in the answer above and `view-echo-area-messages`, type `M-x find-function` ...  In addition, the optional argument in the answer above (i.e., `use-generic-p`) is not needed/used in this example.